# how to change list's type?

Tags: c#

if I have a list like `{"4" , "3"}`,
I want to change that list's type(string to float) -> `{4f , 3f}`.
Is there a function can help me?
I want `{"4" , "3"}` to `{4f , 3f}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float.Parse` in select. Make sure you use `system.linq`.

```cs
var A = new List<string>() {"4", "3"};

var B = A.Select(float.Parse).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks to reply on  my question .
both of you helped me .
Thank you and have a good day

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TOutput>(Converter<T, TOutput> converter)` method in combination with the `float.Parse()` method.
Assuming you have this list of strings:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "4", "3" };
```

...it may be called as:

```
List<float> floats = strings.ConvertAll(s => float.Parse(s));
```

Comment: Thanks to reply on  my question .
both of you helped me .
Thank you and have a good day